# Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on number of values in the table

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
N  numbers
n1 1,2,3
n2 4,6,2
n3 1
n4 2,5
n5 6
```

I need to remove the rows where `numbers` have only one value. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @John Galt 
all the numbers are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way, by splitting the string and finding `len` of list.

```
In [226]: df
Out[226]:
    N numbers
0  n1   1,2,3
1  n2   4,6,2
2  n3       1
3  n4     2,5
4  n5       6

In [227]: df[df.numbers.str.split(',').apply(len) > 1]
Out[227]:
    N numbers
0  n1   1,2,3
1  n2   4,6,2
3  n4     2,5
```

edit: As Nickil Maveli points out, you could use `str.len()` instead of `apply(len)`

Or, if you're data is organized such that, more than one number will have `,` comma, then you can

```
In [229]: df[df.numbers.str.contains(',')]
Out[229]:
    N numbers
0  n1   1,2,3
1  n2   4,6,2
3  n4     2,5
```

Comment: Instead of `apply(len)`, `str.len()` would be a faster vectorized way of checking the number of elements.

Comment: True, but previous on different usecase, few string methods weren't faster. Thanks for this, will update.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the commas directly.  This leaves open the opportunity to adjust the required number of items.

```
df[df.numbers.str.count(',') > 0]

    N numbers
0  n1   1,2,3
1  n2   4,6,2
3  n4     2,5
```